# trying if the user chooses a file a one element is created but instead it is doubled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` that has a file `input` inside of it. If the user chooses a file another `div` should appear to allow the user to choose another file. But, when the user chooses a file the elements are doubled not just one is created.

```
<div class="gal">
  <div class="gal-stf">
    <input class="plus-n" type="file">
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$(".gal").on("click", ".plus-n", function () {
  $(this).last().change(function () {
    $('.gal').append($(".gal-stf").first().clone(true));
  });
});
```

Comment: Your issue is that when the new `input` is created, it already has a file in it. Correct?

Comment: yes and also,
 is that not just one input is created. if there was one another one is created if 2 there are another 2 created then 4 then 8. @fin444

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are running a `.clone(true)` instead of `.clone(false)`. When you clone it with the `true` parameter, you are duplicating the element and its event listeners, and then adding another event listener onto the element. This means that when it is interacted with, the event listener fires two times, creating two new elements. Then four times, creating four new elements.

To fix this issue, simply duplicate the element without event listeners, like so.

```
$(".gal").on("click", ".plus-n", function () {
  $(this).last().change(function () {
    $('.gal').append($(".gal-stf").first().clone(false));
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you very much but the issue that you said it before that when the new input is created, it already has a file in it is still there

Comment: To fix that issue, append a new element instead of a copy. `$('.gal').append('<div class="gal-stf"><input class="plus-n" type="file"></div>');`

Comment: is there is another way to do it with just calling the class name, because it is about 40 lines in the original code

Comment: Try making a template element with a `hidden` class. Duplicate that element, and then paste it onto the end with the `hidden` class.